# Square Drawable, make it an rounded rectangle shape

Tags: android, xml

I have a Square drawable selector. I want to make it an rounded rectangle shape based on a certain `View`. Any one got an idea how to achieve this? I'm using this drawable for `android:background`

Edited: Sorry I forgot to mention, drawable meaning a PNG File.

Comment: Could you provide more details about *`I want to make it an oval shape based on a certain View`*?

Comment: I will set it as a background in a view inside an adapter. If View is in an even row, I will set the view's background drawable as a rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make two slightly different XML files. If it matches the view you're using use one, if not use the other... in the new XML you create, basically copy and paste the one you already have (maybe append "_rounded" to the end of the file name). Then, in the file that you want to have the rounded corners... just add this line, and adjust it (in dip) as you see fit.

```
<corners
    android:radius="4dip"
    />
```

[Edit]

If this is the case, you need to make 2 separate .9.png images. The one that is square, and the one that is rounded. Use a similar naming convention like I had mentioned for the XML above. Use the same test statement...

```
if(viewMeetsCriteria)
    otherView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square);
else
    otherView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_rounded);
```

For additional information on creating .9.png files, see the google tutorial. The 9 patch tool is in your {sdkdir}/tools/. 9 Patch images are images that can freely be stretched based on the amount of space that gets taken up, without looking choppy or forcing you to make several different images. Dev page info here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, it's a PNG file I'm indicating as drawable file.

Comment: Yeah I could do this, I was just wondering what if I only have R.drawable.square at the moment? Can I use this and let Android make the edges rounded?